# Dynamic image tooltip

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

I try to figure out how can I display dynamically a tooltip containing image from byte array.
I don't want to put image href or base64 content on start. It should work dynamically: if user hover something the tooltip will display and obtain image I have in byte array.

Answer (score 2):

You need `DynamicImageResource`. Map it to an URL and override `byte[]  getImageData(IResource.Attributes attributes)`  abstract method that generates image data.

In your WebApplication class:

```
  mount(new MountMapper("/images/my-tooltip", new DynamicImageResource("png") {

      @Override
      protected byte[] getImageData(IResource.Attributes attributes) {
          // TODO your array with data
          return new byte[];
      } 

  }));
```